# Difference between Rudraprashna, Satarudriya, Rudrashtadhyayi, and Rudra Suktam

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, resource, vedic-chanting

Can anyone tell me whether the following four mantras are the same or different? What are the benefits of chanting each and when are they to be chanted?

1. Satarudriya
2. Rudraprashna / Sri Rudram / Namakam & Chamakam
3. Rudrashtadhyayi
4. Rudra Suktam

Can anyone also provide any links to PDFs (in Devanagari script) where I can find these mantras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different, but all praise Shiva and can be found in texts associated with the Yajur Veda.

The **Satarudriya** mantra itself comes from the Yajur Veda, but the Shiva Purana explains that it helps when fighting fever.

> This Dhārā worship is very efficacious in delirium due to fever. At that time **Śatarudriya mantra**, Rudraikādaśa mantra, Rudrajāpya mantra, Puruṣa Sūkta, Ṣaḍaṅga mantra, Mahāmṛtyuñjaya mantra, Gāyatrī, names ending with Namaḥ and beginning with Praṇava or Āgama mantra shall be repeated.
>
> The Dhārā worship **is very excellent in regard to flourishing series of pleasures.**
> [[Shiva Purana 2.1.14]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225982.html)

The Satarudriya comes from the Vajasaneya section of the Yajur Veda; you can read the relevant part [here](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/yajurveda/vajasneyi-madhyandina-samhita/samhita-patha-11-20-adhyaya-16/).

The **Sri Rudram** comes from the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda (Chapter 4), and though there isn't much information contained in the texts about when it's to be said, the content of the mantra itself asks for forgiveness (during Namakam) and for the fulfillment of wishes (during Chamakam). You'd presumably use it when you are looking for one of those.
Here is a [pdf](http://www.vedaunion.org/static/pdf/Sri-Rudram-Text-Anuvakam-1-11-devanagari-transliteration-translation.pdf) to read the original + translation.

The **Rudrashtadhyayi** also comes from the Yajur Veda, here is a [pdf](https://shribaglamukhi.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/rudrashtadhyayi-hindibook-pdf.pdf) to read it online in Devanagari. Again, not much information about when to say it, but it's mostly lines praising Shiva and a few that ask for one's descendants to prosper.

The **Rudra Suktam** can be found in both the Rig Veda and the Yajur Veda. If recited daily in the morning, it is said to offer health and comfort. You can find it online in Hindi [here](https://newsheights.com/rudra-suktam-in-hindi-arth-sahit/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The Shatarudriya in that link only refers to which mantras are part of it instead of actually providing the mantras. Can you provide a link to the whole mantra? Also the viniyog and nyasa are missing for both Shatarudriya and Rudra Suktam

Comment: @user1637645 - see the new link :) I'll work on finding the Rudra Suktam part.