# What is the most important text of Saiva sect?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, chandipath, shaivism

Bhagavad Gita is the key text of the Vaishnavas. Devi Mahatmya (also known as Sri Sri Chandi or Durga Saptashati) is the most important text of the Saktas. Similarly, if we have to peak a single text for Saivites, which one would that be?

It has to be short but at the same time, it has to contain the essential teachings of Saivism.

By the way, I am not looking for a list of important texts. I am looking for **the text**.

Comment: As Saptashati is to Devi, I think Sri Rudram would be to Shiva...

Comment: This is opinion based question..Different Shaiva sects might have different important texts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That's just your opinion!

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes and moreover the answer does not even provide any opinions of any Shaiva sects whatsoever but it is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is without a doubt the Satarudriyam, which even Krishna recommends to Yudhishtira

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b125.htm

> "Yudhishthira said, 'It behoveth thee, O slayer of Madhu, to expound to me that knowledge which thou hast acquired through the grace of Durvasa! O foremost of all persons endued with intelligence, I desire to know everything about the high blessedness and all the names of that high-souled one truly and in detail! 1

> "Vasudeva said, 'I shall recite to thee the good that I have acquired and the fame that I have won through the grace of that high-souled one.

> Verily, I shall discourse to thee on the topic, after having bowed unto Kapardin. O king, **listen to me as I recite to thee that Sata-rudriya which I repeat; with restrained senses, every morning after rising from bed.** The great lord of all creatures, viz., the Grandsire Brahman himself, endued with wealth of penances, composed those Mantras, after having observed especial penances for some time. O sire it is Sankara who created all the creatures in the universe, mobile and immobile. There is no being that is higher, O monarch, than Mahadeva. Verily, he is the highest of all beings in the three worlds. There is no one who is capable of standing before that high-souled Being. Indeed, there is no Being in the three worlds that can be regarded as his equal. When he stands, filled with rage, on the field of battle, the very odour of his body deprives all foes of consciousness and they that are not slain tremble and fall down. His roars are terrible, resembling those of the clouds. Hearing those roars in battle, the very hearts of the deities break in twain. When the wielder of Pinaka becomes angry and assuming a terrible form merely casts his eye upon deity, Asura, Gandharva, or snake, that individual fails to obtain peace of mind by taking shelter in the recesses of even a mountain-cave. When that lord of all creatures, viz., Daksha, desirous of performing a sacrifice, spread his sacrifice out, the dauntless Bhava, giving way to wrath (at Daksha's slight of him), pierced (the embodied) sacrifice, shooting his shaft from his terrible bow, he roared aloud. Indeed, when Maheswara became angry and suddenly pierced with his shaft the embodied form of sacrifice, the deities become filled with grief, losing happiness and tranquillity of heart. In consequence of the twang of his bow-string the whole universe became agitated. The deities and the Asuras, O son of Pritha, all became cheerless and stupefied. The ocean rolled in agitation and the earth trembled to her centre. The hills and mountains began to move from their bases and ran on every side. The vault of the welkin became cracked. All the worlds became enveloped in gloom. Nothing could be seen. The light of all the luminaries became darkened, along with that of the sun himself, O Bharata! The great Rishis, penetrated with fear and desirous of doing good to themselves and the universe, performed the usual rites of propitiation and peace. Meanwhile, Rudra of terrible prowess rushed against the deities. Filled with rage, he tore out the eyes of Bhaga. Incensed with wrath, he assailed Pushan with his foot. He tore out the teeth of that god as he sat employed in eating the large sacrificial ball (called Purodasa). Trembling with fear, the deities bent their heads to Sankara. Without being appeased, Rudra once more placed on his bow-string a sharp and blazing arrow. Beholding his prowess, the deities and the Rishis became all alarmed. Those foremost of gods began to pacify him! Joining their hands in reverence, they began to recite the Sata-rudriya Mantras. At last Maheswara, thus praised by the deities, became gratified.

Unfortunately, at the prsent time, only South Indian Brahmins seem to be able to chant these mantras with proper gravitas:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIG6-HG5VX4

The Satarudriyam is one of the very pillars of Hinduism.

Comment: can you please mention briefly what is satarudriyam? can you please add a link to the text satarudriyam?

Comment: Shatarudriya is the 16th chapter of the Shukla Yajurveda Samhita.

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/difference-between-rudraprashna-satarudriya-rudrashtadhyayi-and-rudra-suktam/55821#55821) answer of mine.